# Axios get request getting cors issue

Tags: reactjs, cors, axios

i'm trying to get some data from some endpoint.

I can't share the url of endpoint here but problem with cors.

when i'm using postman everything is ok.

But when make get request from my react app via axios i'm getting this error:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "origin"
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://some.com/products.json' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

here is my request:

```
const baseUrl = "http://some.com/products.json"
const axiosConfig = {
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }
};

      axios
      .get(baseUrl, axiosConfig)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
```

i tried many things but i can't figure out with this.

Comment: Getting response from php ?

Comment: @RiponUddin Yes, I'm struggling to get Response from php server on Vue js. Any solution you would suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS in your server, if you have access to your server add the following line to your server.

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'
```

for nodejs server

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
}
```

for local development you can bypass cors by disabling chrome security, open chrome using `--disable-web-security` flag, close all instances of Chrome

```
# Open chrome and disable security
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="/Users/junius/chrome/"

# Open Microsoft Edge
open -a Microsoft\ Edge --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="/Users/junius/chrome/"
```

Comment: so i need to tell about this problem to backend developer who gave me this endpoint?

Comment: @user3348410 yes but for now there's a way to bypass this error, whic os are you using?

Comment: I'm using mac os

Comment: what if you don't have access to the backend?

Answer (score -2):

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

As your error states, perhaps the problem will be solved if you specify the header like this.

```
headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }
```

Similar issue was reported on github.

> Getting 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked' on a GET request #853 
>   https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/853

Comment: do you have access to your server and which server are you using?